# DataTables Filter Cell Content not DB Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

Using DataTables 1.10.19

I have a MySQL DB, the structure is as follows;

```
+------+-----------------+----------+----------+
| name | email           | status   | complete |    
+------+-----------------+----------+----------+
| Joe  | me@example.com  | 1        |1         |
+------+-----------------+----------+----------+
| Jim  | you@example.com | 1        |0         |
+------+-----------------+----------+----------+
| Sara | him@example.com | 0        |0         |
+------+-----------------+----------+----------+
```

I'm using [this script](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php) to retrieve data from the db.

My datatable filter works as expected when searching for `0` and `1`, but this filters **both** `status` and `complete` columns. I would like to search for the *words* `active` / `inactive` and `complete` / `incomplete` instead of  `1` and `0`.

I'm using the datatables [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to render a custom output in these columns based on the row results.

My DataTable code is;

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajaxSource": "results.php", // output below
    "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
    }, {
        "data": "email"
    }, {
        "data": "status",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
            // row[2] returns an int of 0 or 1 from the db. inactive/active
            if (row[2] == 0) {
                return `inactive`;
            }
            if (row[2] == 1) {
                return `active`;
            }
        }
    }, {
        "data": "complete",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
            // row[2] returns an int of 0 or 1 from the db. incomplete/complete
            if (row[3] == 0) {
                return `incomplete`;
            }
            if (row[3] == 1) {
                return `complete`;
            }
        }
    }, ]
});
```

The `results.php` file returns the following;

```
"data": [
    [
      "Joe",
      "me@example.com  ",
      "1",
      "1",
    ],
    [
      "Jim",
      "you@example.com  ",
      "1",
      "0",
    ],
    [
      "Sara",
      "him@example.com  ",
      "0",
      "0",
    ],
]
```

My front end HTML table looks like this;

```
+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| name | email           | status   |complete    |
+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Joe  | me@example.com  | active   |complete    |
+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Jim  | you@example.com | active   |incomplete  | 
+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Sara | him@example.com | inactive |incomplete  |
+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
```

Currently the filter seems to filter the db `int` value and not the cell text.

How can I search for the words instead of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work just fine. Typing "Inactive" shows only Sara as a result. What are you doing differently?

Edit: I have updated the snippet to match your latest code. It seems you are passing down an array of arrays for your data, so I am surprised that your table is even initializing, as the `data` options are not valid in that case (how can `data` select the `"name"` attribute if it doesn't exist in your result set? It should be the array index). After updating the data options to the array index, the table searches your rendered table correctly. Searching "Incomplete" returns Jim/ Sara, while searching "Inactive" returns Sara.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = getDummyData();
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": [{
        "data": 0
      },
      {
        "data": 1
      },
      {
        "data": 2,
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          // row[2] returns an int of 0 or 1 from the db. inactive/active
          if (data == 0) {
            return `inactive`;
          }
          if (data == 1) {
            return `active`;
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "data": 3,
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          // row[2] returns an int of 0 or 1 from the db. incomplete/complete
          if (data == 0) {
            return `incomplete`;
          }
          if (data == 1) {
            return `complete`;
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  });
});

function getDummyData() {
  return [
    [
      "Joe",
      "me@example.com  ",
      "1",
      "1",
    ],
    [
      "Jim",
      "you@example.com  ",
      "1",
      "0",
    ],
    [
      "Sara",
      "him@example.com  ",
      "0",
      "0",
    ],
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>complete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've updated my response. After integrating your data format, I am still able to search the data correctly. The only differences now is that I commented out `data` options because they are not valid with your result set, and that I am using static data, rather than ajax sourced data.

Comment: If you are still having issues, try testing it with static data so we can eliminate the difference of the data source as the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going round in circles, I'm using this script to retrieve db results if that helps https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php